# How to make sections in a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to cut my bibliography into different sections.
For example I would like something looking like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\section{Historical review of capacity in optical telecommunication networks},

\bibitem{Chap0-Handbook} 
    B. Mukherjee et al.,
    \textit{Springer Handbook of Optical Networks},
    Springer Cham, 10/2020,
    ISBN: 978-3-030-16249-8,
    \mydoi{10.1007/978-3-030-16250-4},

\bibitem{Chap0-RUNGE}
     P.K. Runge,
    \textit{An experimental 50 Mb/s fiber optic PCM repeater},
    Trans. Comm., Vol COM-24, No. 4, 04/1976,
    \mydoi{10.1109/TCOM.1976.1093308}

\section{Monitoring in optical networks},

\bibitem{Chap1-Christodoulopoulos}
    K. Christodoulopoulos et. al,
    \textit{Toward efficient, reliable, and autonomous optical networks:
    the ORCHESTRA solution},
    IEEE J. Opt. Commun. Netw., Sept. 2019, Vol 11, No. 9,
    doi: \url{10.1109/JLT.2020.2984270}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a bibliography with sections in LaTeX, you can use the `biblatex` package with custom categories for each section. Here's an example:

1. First, install the biblatex` package in your preamble:

```
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

2. Define your categories:

```
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{historical_review}
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{monitoring}
```

3. Assign bibliography entries to their respective categories:

```
\addtocategory{historical_review}{Chap0-Handbook,Chap0-RUNGE}
\addtocategory{monitoring}{Chap1-Christodoulopoulos}
```

4. Add your bibliography file (assuming you are using a `.bib` file):

```
\addbibresource{your_bib_file.bib}
```

5. Print the bibliography with sections:

```
\printbibheading
\section*{Historical review of capacity in optical telecommunication networks}
\printbibliography[category=historical_review,heading=none]

\section*{Monitoring in optical networks}
\printbibliography[category=monitoring,heading=none]
```

Make sure you replace `your_bib_file.bib` with the name of your actual .bib file.

In your `.bib` file, your entries should look like this:

```
@book{Chap0-Handbook,
    author = {B. Mukherjee et al.},
    title = {Springer Handbook of Optical Networks},
    publisher = {Springer Cham},
    year = {2020},
    month = {10},
    isbn = {978-3-030-16249-8},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-030-16250-4},
}

@article{Chap0-RUNGE,
    author = {P.K. Runge},
    title = {An experimental 50 Mb/s fiber optic PCM repeater},
    journal = {Trans. Comm.},
    volume = {COM-24},
    number = {4},
    year = {1976},
    month = {04},
    doi = {10.1109/TCOM.1976.1093308},
}

@article{Chap1-Christodoulopoulos,
    author = {K. Christodoulopoulos et. al},
    title = {Toward efficient, reliable, and autonomous optical networks: the ORCHESTRA solution},
    journal = {IEEE J. Opt. Commun. Netw.},
    volume = {11},
    number = {9},
    year = {2019},
    month = {09},
    doi = {10.1109/JLT.2020.2984270},
}
```

**EDIT**: AS @louis wants an example for a way to have the bibliography items inside LaTeX-script here is a solution:

You can create a custom bibliography with sections directly within your LaTeX document using the `enumitem` and `hyperref` packages. Here's how:

1. First, add the `enumitem` and `hyperref` packages to your preamble:

   ```latex
   \usepackage{enumitem}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   ```
2. Create a custom bibliography list:

   ```latex
   \newlist{bibsection}{enumerate}{1}
   \setlist[bibsection]{label={[\arabic*]},itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*,align=left}
   ```
3. Define your bibliography items within sections:

   ```latex
   \begin{bibsection}

   \section*{Historical review of capacity in optical telecommunication networks}

   \item B. Mukherjee et al.,
       \textit{Springer Handbook of Optical Networks},
       Springer Cham, 10/2020,
       ISBN: 978-3-030-16249-8,
       \href{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-16250-4}{doi:10.1007/978-3-030-16250-4}

   \item P.K. Runge,
       \textit{An experimental 50 Mb/s fiber optic PCM repeater},
       Trans. Comm., Vol COM-24, No. 4, 04/1976,
       \href{https://doi.org/10.1109/TCOM.1976.1093308}{doi:10.1109/TCOM.1976.1093308}

   \section*{Monitoring in optical networks}

   \item K. Christodoulopoulos et. al,
       \textit{Toward efficient, reliable, and autonomous optical networks:
       the ORCHESTRA solution},
       IEEE J. Opt. Commun. Netw., Sept. 2019, Vol 11, No. 9,
       \href{https://doi.org/10.1109/JLT.2020.2984270}{doi:10.1109/JLT.2020.2984270}

   \end{bibsection}
   ```

This code snippet creates a custom enumerated list for your bibliography and separates the items by sections. The result is a bibliography that resembles the one in your original question, without the need for a `.bib` file.

Tough, I would highly recommend to outsource the `.bib` file whenever possible. This makes debugging much easier and might help to keep the original document file in a more structured way!

EDIT II : It seems their was a misunderstanding regarding the question. The following solution provides a way to add a custom Reference section, while creating custom bibitems.

To create a custom bibliography with sections in LaTeX without using a `.bib` file, you can use the `etaremune` package for reverse enumeration and the `hyperref` package for clickable DOIs. Here's how:

1. Add the `etaremune` and `hyperref` packages to your preamble:

   ```latex
   \usepackage{etaremune}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   ```
2. Create custom commands for easy citation and reference:

   ```latex
   \newcommand{\customcite}[1]{[\ref{#1}]}
   \newcommand{\custombibitem}[1]{\item \label{#1}}
   ```
3. Define your bibliography items within sections:

   ```latex
   \section*{References}

   \section*{Historical review of capacity in optical telecommunication networks}
   \begin{etaremune}

   \custombibitem{Chap0-Handbook}
   B. Mukherjee et al.,
   \textit{Springer Handbook of Optical Networks},
   Springer Cham, 10/2020,
   ISBN: 978-3-030-16249-8,
   \href{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-16250-4}{doi:10.1007/978-3-030-16250-4}

   \custombibitem{Chap0-RUNGE}
   P.K. Runge,
   \textit{An experimental 50 Mb/s fiber optic PCM repeater},
   Trans. Comm., Vol COM-24, No. 4, 04/1976,
   \href{https://doi.org/10.1109/TCOM.1976.1093308}{doi:10.1109/TCOM.1976.1093308}

   \end{etaremune}

   \section*{Monitoring in optical networks}
   \begin{etaremune}

   \custombibitem{Chap1-Christodoulopoulos}
   K. Christodoulopoulos et. al,
   \textit{Toward efficient, reliable, and autonomous optical networks:
   the ORCHESTRA solution},
   IEEE J. Opt. Commun. Netw., Sept. 2019, Vol 11, No. 9,
   \href{https://doi.org/10.1109/JLT.2020.2984270}{doi:10.1109/JLT.2020.2984270}

   \end{etaremune}
   ```
4. Now, you can use `\customcite{}` to cite references in your text, like this:

   ```latex
   As mentioned in \customcite{Chap0-Handbook}, optical networks have a rich history.
   ```

`\customcite{}` command. The `etaremune` package provides a reverse enumeration for the bibliography items, so the list will be numbered in descending order. If you prefer ascending order, simply replace `etaremune` with `enumerate`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. However I was wondering if there was something much simpler? As I don't have Zotero or else, I type all the bibliography myself and i have dozens of references. Even just a simple bold text in between of my bibliography list would be enough... thx again

Comment: By the way, I do not write my bibliography in a .bib but in a .tex as in articles templates

Comment: Sure, this is possible. Please check my EDIT.

Comment: Ok nice thanks, it is working but it still raises an error: "There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table." Moreover, in your solution, how the call to the reference is performed? still with \cite{}? thanks again

Comment: See my last edit.

Comment: It looks to work perfectly, thanks a ton for ur time! :)

Comment: I have 2 little more questions and sorry for that. Before with \cite, if we put several references as input we got in the pdf something like [2,6,15] (just an example). But here it   yields [??]. How to enable multiple labels? I tried with the cleveref package and by changing \ref by \cref in the newcommand but it gives actually the calling name like [Chap0-Pointurier,Chap1-Christodoulopoulos] and not the corresponding numbers anymore... Last question, I also tried to change the braket style for "[ ]" but does not work, do you have any idea? thanks a lot!