# How to remove section number in TOC while keeping the nummeration

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have a bibliography whose items are inside a `LaTeX`-script (as in journal templates). Here ["How to make sections in a bibliography"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681311/how-to-make-sections-in-a-bibliography/681327?noredirect=1#comment1690791_681327) someone helped me to create sections in my bibliography.

I want to keep the numbers in my bibliography to refer to the section where it was employed, but I don't want those sections to appear in the TOC. So using a star (*) after the keyword is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I thought I could use the  `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth` counters, but the level passed to `\@startsection` is not the same level being passed to `\@dottedtocline`.  Worse, `section` is both the counter name and is used for `\l@section` which sets the level for `todepth`.

Comment: It seems you want numbered sections but they should not show in the table of contents. Then use `\addtocontents{toc}{\string\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}` before inserting the numbered sections. And add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{<whatever, perhaps 2 or 3>}` immediately after your `\tableofcontents`, so that when the `\tableofcontents` is executed it will at the end reset the `tocdepth`.  This is in case you use `hyperref` because the value of `tocdepth` influences decisions of `hyperref` for bookmarks.  If you don't use `hyperref` you do not need to reset the `tocdepth`  after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: This works to hide the selected sections, but erases all the following chapters/sections from the toc... thx btw

Answer (score 0):

This creates `\mysection` for sections with numbers but will not appear in the TOC.  It basically duplicates `\section` except that `\l@mysection` does nothing.

Note that this depends on the document class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\c@mysection=\c@section
\let\themysection=\thesection
\newcommand{\mysection}{\@startsection{mysection}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\let\mysectionmark\sectionmark
\newcommand*\l@mysection[2]{}% do nothing
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Normal section}

\mysection{A special section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this works well but creates a lot of errors that I don't understand much, thanks a lot

Comment: Which is why one should always provide a MWE.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest is to use

```latex
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\iffalse}
\section{numbered but not displayed by TOC}
...
\section{one last one}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}
```

Assuming I did understand correctly the query.

Comment: Thanks but as the above comments this works to hide the selected sections, but erases all the following chapters/sections from the toc... thx again!!

Comment: @louis did you notice this answer is not the same as the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681530/how-to-remove-section-numero-in-toc-while-keeping-the-numerotation/681543?noredirect=1#comment1691085_681530) to which you made the very same comment? I thought in that comment that the sections you wanted to hide were at very end of your file.  But the method in my answer is different, and if you apply it, what you say is simply impossible.

Comment: yes I noticed the answers you mention are different and I tried both but raise the same error, that's why my comments are similar. But maybe I misimplemented it. I am sorry if I have been a bit confusing...

Comment: @louis nothing to worry; so you do get errors... that's strange! I am glad you have a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seem to work (but I don't have the reference anymore):

```
\newcommand*{\BeginNoToc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \edef\protect\SavedTocDepth{\protect\the\protect\value{tocdepth}}%
  }%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\EndNoToc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\protect\SavedTocDepth}%
  }%
}
```

Thanks a ton everybody :)

Comment: this will work but is needlessly more complex than the `\iffalse..\fi` method

Comment: In theory it can happen with this method that some commands are encountered in the toc file which will be executed but belong to the material which is supposedly skipped (perhaps some babel language changes for example). Admittedly the possibility is very remote so for all purposes this does work.